# Stop keyboard from pushing aligned to bottom view

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout

I've a `ConstraintLayout` with the following hierarchy:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <EditText
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>

   <RecyclerView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="Button"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="EditText"/>

   <Button
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

When the `EditText` gains focus the keyboard pops up pushing the `Button` (and therefore the `RecyclerView`) up. I don't want that to happen, let the keyboard go free without pushing any view.

I've tried a lot of `android:windowSoftInputMode` combinations (example below) with no luck. Also the `ScrollView` "hack" but without luck either.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S: Only solution I can think of is hiding the `Button` when the keyboard shows up.

Comment: Use adjustPan so the screen isn't resized and the entire screen is just moved up.  Or use none so that the keyboard comes up over the top of your view-  but in that case you may not be able to see what the user is typing, as it may be covered.  Hiding the button when the keyboard comes up isn't possible, as there is no reliable way to detect that.  There's hacks, but those hacks aren't always correct.

Comment: Using adjustPan or adjustNothing doesn't work, the button is pushed up.

Comment: If adjust nothing did anything, you used it in the wrong place. Pan will move the button up, but it will move the entire screen up- the relative positioning will remain the same.

Comment: <activity android:name=".Activity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

Comment: @GuilhE Hi, i'm having the EXACT SAME issue. Did you ever come up with a solution with constraintLayout  for the keyboard to pop up without moving everything else?

Comment: @iBEK unfortunately not. I had to redesign the layout. You could be listening for the keyboard changes and hide the button when it's visible, but it's clunky.

Answer (score 3):

Try to user `adjustNothing` instead of `adjustPan`

```
<activity
     ...
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```